# Read JSON column from SQL Table and concat JSON array into string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database

I'm trying to read data from a table who has multiple columns and one of them is JSON data. Inside this JSON there is an array of JSON's that I want to get one specific value.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "FirstName": "Carlos",
    "LastName": "Perez",
    "PhoneNumbers": [{
        "PhoneNumber": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "PhoneNumber": "987654321"
    }]
}
```

What I want is to read this JSON column so it gives me **only the phones numbers**.

I want to get a result like this:

| Id | Column 1 | Column 2 | JSON Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | Value 2 | 123456789, 987654321 |

Comment: This looks like a simple query to get the data from the JSOn, using `OPENJSON`, and then string aggregation. There's plenty of examples.om how to do both of these things, what about the wealth of information out there didn't you understand? What about your attempts didn't work? What *were* your attempts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question can be improved by including a snippet of what you've done/tried and perhaps the challenge with that you can get tailored help with context, in any case, here's a `SQL` query to achieve your desired result.

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    Column1,
    Column2,
    JSON_QUERY(YourJSONColumn, '$.PhoneNumbers[*].PhoneNumber') AS PhoneNumbers,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + PhoneNumber
        FROM OPENJSON(YourJSONColumn, '$.PhoneNumbers')
        WITH (PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(255) '$.PhoneNumber')
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ConcatenatedPhoneNumbers
FROM YourTable;
```

Remember to replace `YourTable` with the actual name of your table and `YourJSONColumn` with the name of your JSON column

Edit:
Optimising the query

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    Column1,
    Column2,
    JSON_QUERY(YourJSONColumn, '$.PhoneNumbers') AS PhoneNumbers,
    STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE(phoneNumber.value, '$.PhoneNumber'), ', ') AS ConcatenatedPhoneNumbers
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YourJSONColumn, '$.PhoneNumbers') 
    WITH (PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(255) '$.PhoneNumber') AS phoneNumber
GROUP BY Id, Column1, Column2, YourJSONColumn;
```

Comment: Why use the old `FOR XML PATH` method here?

Comment: I don't see any sign that [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) supports `*`

Comment: I had to make some adjustments, but it helped a lot! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MartinSmith @ThomA using the `FOR XML PATH` method to concatenate phone numbers from a JSON column and then applying `JSON_QUERY` to extract an array of phone numbers. The STUFF function is used to remove the leading comma from the concatenated phone numbers.


                                                     
It's important to note that there was no context or way to measure the challenge faced and so it was a long wild shot